# Primary monitor desktop flickering when 2nd monitor connected

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, multi-monitor, laptop

So, I'm very fond of using a 2nd monitor located physically over my laptop. After switching to Linux Mint 19.2 Tina I've started to have a very strange behavior.

When I plug in the external monitor (HDMI) into the laptop I start to get a flickering situation on the background desktop **only** when the location of the 2dary display is on the top of the laptop.
**If I set the location to any of the sides of the primary screen (laptop), the issue doesn't occurs.**

The flickering issue is:

- Background image disappears randomly and by sectors on the screen. Usually when I move a window from one place to another (inside the same display)
- All the desktop (primary screen) refreshes from time to time.

Any ideas?